# Redirect to another page/view by javascript with 2 arrays - Laravel 5

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

Hi guys I am trying to return/pass 2 arrays after redirect,

This is my ajax

```
$.ajax({
method: 'POST',
url: urlAvaliarSubordinor,
data: {pval: pval, _token: subToken},
success: function(result) {
  location.href = "http://localhost/project/avaliacao";
}

  //console.log(data);
});
```

And this is my Controller

```
return response()->json([
        'list_one' => $list_one,
        'list_two'  => $list_two 
]);
```

So I want to redirect to the page 'avaliacao' and with access/pass of the 2 arrays.. My knowledge of HTTP Status Codes is weak , I am currently reading materials online but it all sounds like ancient script to me, Please if anyone can just point me to something that might help me or an explanation on how to pass data in url on javascript

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has many different types of responses that you can send back to your application. I usually send back data formatted in json since its super easy to work with for javascript.

```
return response()->json([
                           'name' => 'Abigail',
                           'state' => 'CA'
                         ]);
```

In the docs you can see all the other types of responses that can be used. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses

Comment: ive done this before a simple return view ... I dont know why it returns the entire html page

Comment: also I need to redirect to another page with the 2 arrays, I have tried return redirect()->with(['list'=>$list]); no luck

Comment: tried,   return redirect()->route('login');  and it does the same thing